# Hide export button in ng-admin list view

Tags: ng-admin

In version 0.7 of ng-admin I could hide the `Export` button in list view with

`.actions(['batch', 'create'])`

However, in version 0.8 this also hides the newly introduced `Add filter` button. So my question is, how can I hide only the `Export` button in ng-admin 0.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed in the master branch (currently labelled 0.9-dev) a little while ago (cf https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin/pull/661). I suggest you use this master branch until 0.9 is released.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to pass an empty string in actions

```
.actions([''])
```

Comment: it works, and if you want to show just filters, write

.actions(['filter'])